# Missing types in ServiceStack 3.9.71

Tags: c#, razor, mono, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I am developing service infrastructure (admin panel + webservices) on `ServiceStack` **3.9.71**. When I started development process, was no errors or warnings and all projects were  compiled and run perfect. Problems appeared when I tried to deploy apps on Linux: admin control panel does not started there (`mono fastcgi-server4`).

I backuped all and removed all `ServiceStack` and `ServiceStack Razor` dependencies from all projects in solution, and then re-installed them. After that, in compiler log appears lot of warnings of missed types. I tried to run apps, but they crash with errors.

Compiler log is listed below. I'm using russian version of `Visual Studio 2012 Express`, so all messages I translated with Google Translator.

```
1>------ Rebuilding all files started: Project: App.Common, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  App.Common -> d:\projects\app\App.Common\bin\Debug\App.Common.dll
2>------ Rebuilding all files started: Project: App.Models, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Rebuilding all files started: Project: App.Roles, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  App.Models -> d:\projects\app\App.Models\bin\Debug\App.Models.dll
3>  App.Roles -> d:\projects\app\App.Roles\bin\Debug\App.Roles.dll
4>------ Rebuilding all files started: Project: App.ServiceDTO, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>  App.ServiceDTO -> d:\projects\app\App.ServiceDTO\bin\Debug\App.ServiceDTO.dll
5>------ Rebuilding all files started: Project: App.Services, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
6>------ Rebuilding all files started: Project: App.Administration, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IServiceRunner`1", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IServiceRunner`1", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ApiMemberAttribute", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll"
5>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll"
5>  App.Services -> d:\projects\app\App.Services\bin\App.Services.dll
7>------ Rebuilding all files started: Project: App.Tests, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IServiceRunner`1", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IServiceRunner`1", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ApiMemberAttribute", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Razor.3.9.71\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Razor.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Razor.3.9.71\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Razor.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Razor.3.9.71\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Razor.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Razor.3.9.71\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Razor.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
6>  App.Administration -> d:\projects\app\App.Administration\bin\App.Administration.dll
7>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
7>  App.Tests -> d:\projects\app\App.Tests\bin\Debug\App.Tests.dll
8>------ Rebuilding all files started: Project: App, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
8>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
8>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
8>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IServiceRunner`1", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
8>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
8>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
8>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
8>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IServiceRunner`1", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
8>d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Could not find type "ServiceStack.IO.IVirtualPathProvider", which, according to the link must be defined in "d:\projects\app\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll"
8>  App -> d:\projects\app\App\bin\Debug\App.exe
========== Rebuilding all: successful: 8 errors: 0, skipped: 0 ==========
```

I didn't found same problems on other project, that is too based on ServiceStack 3.9.71, what I developed two months ago.

Answer (score 6):

I solved that problem by step-by-step reinstalling **all** `ServiceStack`'s dependencies:

```
Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71
Install-Package ServiceStack.Common -Version 3.9.71
Install-Package ServiceStack.Text -Version 3.9.71

# optionally
Install-Package ServiceStack.Razor -Version 3.9.71
```

Be carefull to remove all entries for `ServiceStack` from `packages.config` in each project where You use it. I also deleted `packages` folder from solution. I discovered that problem was by automated linking **>4.0** version libraries in packages repository.

Comment: This fixes it but you need to do it in the opposite order because of their dependencies